# Jquery datepicker is not working in MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-datepicker

Here i am using a jquery datepicker from this sample http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2.
It is working fine but the problem is after clicking the submit button if there is any mandatory field validation error,the next time when i click the textbox jquery datepicker is not working means the script is not loading after submit click.it is throwing the error in firebug console like

```
TypeError: $(...).datebox is not a function
$('#txtstartdate').datebox('open');
```

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtstartdate').live('click', function () {
        $('#txtstartdate').datebox('open');
        $("#txtstartdate").datebox("option", {
            mode: "calbox",
            highDatesAlt: ["2011-11-09", "2011-11-10"],
            highDates: ["2011-11-02", "2011-11-03"],
            pickPageOAHighButtonTheme: "b"
        });
    });
 });
```

and

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, new { @name = "mydate", @id = "txtstartdate",  style = "height:20px; font-size:10px;", data_role = "datebox", data_options = "{\"mode\":\"calbox\",\"useButton\": false}" })
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

as the firebug error suggest the browser could not find the function being used within the script can you make sure that the dependencies of the datebox is availiable after the submit call.
also try to send the dependencies with the view itself so that on every rendering of the view page at the client end it hold these js file with in it.